# Odoo ORM api onchange not working on many2many - odoo 13

Tags: orm, odoo, onchange, odoo-13

Odoo ORM api onchange not working on many2many - odoo 13.

Trying to update sale_line's m2m field when product is changed in form view. It's not working.

```
@api.onchange("product_id")
def _fetch_mf_ids(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.mf_ids = [
            (6, 0, [x.id for x in rec.product_id.mf_ids])
        ]
```

Getting non-stored values for this m2m rec in sale_order_line when I print `rec.mf_ids`

```
product.mf.pgm(<NewId origin=5>, <NewId origin=7>)
```

Comment: Try to use this ```[(6, 0, [x for x in rec.product_id.mf_ids.ids])]``` or ```[(6, 0, rec.product_id.mf_ids.ids)]```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in onchange method you will generally get this issue of `(<NewId origin=5>, <NewId origin=7>)` so to get the values use

> rec._origin.mf_ids

you will get the field values